# Get current datetime using moment-timezone

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, moment-timezone

I am trying to get the current datetime using moment-timezone within Nodejs following the instructions found here: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/ where it states: *moment().tz(String) does converting to provided time zone*

```
'use strict';

const moment = require('moment-timezone');

exports.handler = async (context, req) => {
    const todayMoment = moment().tz('America/Chicago');

    return {
       statusCode: 200,
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/text'},
       body: todayMoment
    };
}
```

will return the UTC time, not the UTC time in Central Time Zone (running within Azure Function). For example, it returns 2022-11-29T04:11:07.744Z rather than 2022-11-28T22:11: 07.744Z

How do I get the current date/time within the Central Time Zone?

BTW, I also tried:

```
let now = moment();
let todayMoment = moment.tz(now, 'America/Chicago');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per wiki,
Central Standard Time (CST) is six hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Hence to get Central Standard Time from UTC you need to subtract 6 hours.

```
'use strict';

const moment = require('moment-timezone');

let now = moment();
let todayMoment = moment.tz(now, 'America/Chicago');

console.log(todayMoment.subtract(6, 'hours').format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: Why would I have to know that and hardcode that information into the program?  By specifying a particular timezone, in this case, 'America/Chicago', moment-timezone should automatically subtract 6 hours from the UTC time.